# Hop variety resources

Tags: beer, hops

Are there any good resources for finding out which hop varieties have similar aroma, flavour and bittering potential.  E.g. a place to lookup a hop could be substituted for another hop for bittering for flavor and for aroma?

The list on wikipedia is a good starting point, but it's not very well cross referenced - because that is not what wikipedia is for.

Answer (score 5):

Hopunion's Hop Variet Databook is a great resource.

http://hopunion.com/17_HopVarieties.cfm?p3=open

Answer (score 3):

I have been doing a lot of hop chemistry research and if you want a more then basic comparison check this site out
http://beerlegends.com/hops-varieties Click on a hop variety you are interested in and there will be a chart for every characteristic of a hop you could ever want to know. 
Get to know your *hop oil fractions (or compositions)*(Myrcene Humulene Caryophyllene and Farnesene), it's the last chart at the bottom. If you don't know much about hop oils a click on the oil name next to the chart will take you to a brief description and sort the hops by that specific oil. besides charts it also has a hop substitute list and common beer styles list as well

Comment: +1 I really like this resource....extremely detailed yet still easy to pull out the basic info you are looking for.

Comment: This has displaced the resources I used to reference.  I wish I could upvote it again.

Answer (score 2):

I keep these bookmarked:

http://homebrewandbeer.com/hops.html

http://hopschart.com/zoom

Answer (score 1):

http://www.brew-dudes.com/ are fine

Comment: More specifically the hops category: http://www.brew-dudes.com/category/hops where they blog about the profile of an individual variety occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

[BeerSmith](http://beersmith.com/hop-list/) has a pretty good list, but I'm going to upvote and bookmark Denny's link immediately.

There's also the [variety book by USA Hops](http://usahops.org/userfiles/file/HGA%20BCI%20Reports/HGA%20Variety%20Manual%20-%20English%20%28updated%20March%202011%29.pdf) that seems comparable to the one from HopUnion that Denny provided.  Unfortunately, it only has American hops.